# Relying on odometry for 100 meters

Tags: odometry, dead-reckoning

I am using 4 mecanum wheeled robot and have recently tested its wheel odometry. It was accurate to about 5-10 cm.

How sensible is it to use the wheel odometry for 100 meters after which I have some external sensors that can correct the pose and orientation?

P.S. For orientation estimation I am using IMU, wheel odometry is only used for translational calculation

Comment: 5-10 cm error over a 100 m seems pretty good

Comment: @jsotola What do you usually get?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Alisher Kassymov.  Unfortunately, it might be [hard for our members to answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/) this question because odometry error depends so much on the specifics of your robot and environment.  We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*.  Can you edit the question to add detail, diagrams, and pictures?

Answer (score 1):

5-10cm isn't too bad after 100m. Obviously this is kind of subjective because I don't know what hardware you are using. You could be using the cheapest encoders on the market for all I know. That being said, it's pretty good. I'd expect to see around 0.1% error in odometry without anything fancy like SLAM.